# INSERT INTO statement in a specific column

Tags: ms-access, insert-into

For example i have table with a different field names(column), lets say 5 columns and all of them are empty. And i wanted to insert data in one specific column. Is it possible? I'm looking for example of this, but unlucky to find one. Most of insert into statements examples required all columns to be filled. If possible, can you give me the correct syntax? I'm sorry if i'm lacking research or it's already been asked, it's ok if you will redirect me to the link.

Comment: Insert or update? if you insert in only one of five, what about the other four columns, leave empty?

Comment: Insert. Yeah, then later part of the program, will insert the values to the remaining column.

Answer (score 1):

If you want insert on `column3`, leaving empty the other:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5)
VALUES ("","","VALUE","","");
```

The other part of program would `UPDATE` the other columns:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,column4=value4,column5=value5
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

Comment: I come up with that solution, thanks anyway. How bout if different datatype? i.e. Date/Time, Yes/No.

Comment: It does not matter the datatype, is the same way, only take care of string to wrap with `"`

Comment: Btw im using this syntax in c#, it looks like this is not working, maybe something to be fixed, could you tell?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on how to construct an `INSERT INTO` statement is here: [INSERT INTO Statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb208861(v=office.12).aspx).

But basically, you just need to be explicit about which columns you want to insert values for, and omit the other ones, like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (colname) VALUES ('colvalue')
```

What happens to the fields you omit?  The documentation says:

> When you do not specify each field, the default value or `Null` is inserted for missing columns.

Comment: if i have 2 values to be inserted in 2 different columns, does this work: `INSERT INTO table ([colname1], [colname2]) VALUES ("val1","val2")`

Comment: Yes, without the `[]`, in this way `INSERT INTO table (colname1, colname2) VALUES ("val1","val2");`

Comment: Yes, your statement structure looks good. Using the `[]` square brackets around the column names is fine, just not strictly necessary, unless your column names have spaces.  And how you specify the actual values will depend on the data type.  But if it's text, I think you can wrap the string value in either single quotes or double quotes.  But to be standard, better to use single quotes, and it will spare you some trouble with having to worry about escaping the double quotes if you are writing your queries in C#.